# Cs50 Vigenere code gives unexpected output when using the proper ASCII Values

Tags: c, ascii, cs50, vigenere

I have written this code for the Vigenere problem in cs50.
However it doesn´t work as expected when I print the enciphered letters I use 58 and 90 instead of 65 and 97.(the ASCII values for A and a)

Doing so gives me the result I wanted however I dont understand why it does. It gives me the wrong enciphered Text when subtracting by 'a' or 'A',whichdoesn´t make any sense to me.

I looked up some different solutions and they all subtract with 'a' or 'A' to get to alphabetical Index,however doing this doesn´t work for me.

I really can´t figure out why I have to use these Values in my code maybe anyone can help me understand what went wrong or where my logical mistake is.

Thanks in Advance.

edit: I changed

k[z] = tolower(k[z]); to k[z] = toupper(k[z] - 'A');

and I also changed

printf("%c",(((p[j]- 58) + k[l % strlen(k)]) % 26) + 'A'); to printf("%c",(((p[j]- 'A' -6) + k[l % strlen(k)]) % 26) + 'A');

the -6 is because that gives me the right output meaning something is still off

key:       bacon

plaintext: Meet me at the park at eleven am

expected output :        Negh zf av huf pcfx bt gzrwep oz

actual output with the -6: Negh zf av huf pcfx bt gzrwep oz

actual output without -6 : Tkmn fl gb nal vild hz mfxckv uf

Somehow all values are off by -6 and I don´t know why

Also k.size() gave me errors so I kept strlen().

```
int main(int argc,string argv[])
{

//checks if only one argument was typed
if (argc != 2)
{
    printf("Error");
    return 1;
}

//assigns the keyword argv[1] to k
string k = argv[argc -1];
//check if key is alphabetical only
for (int i = 0 , n = strlen(k); i < n; i++)
{
    if(!isalpha(k[i]))
    {
        printf("Key is not alphabetical");
        return 1;
    }
}
printf("Key Valid\n");
//convert key to lowercase only
for(int z = 0; k[z]; z++)
{
    k[z] = tolower(k[z]);
}

string p = get_string("Plaintext: ");
//iterate over p
//l is incremented only when the char is alphabetical and is used as index for k
for (int j = 0,l = 0 , o = strlen(p);j < o ;j++)
{

    if(isalpha(p[j]))
    {
        if(isupper(p[j]))
        {
            //print enciphered letter
            printf("%c",(((p[j]- 58) + k[l % strlen(k)]) % 26) + 'A');
        }
        else if(islower(p[j]))
        {
            //print enciphered letter
            printf("%c",(((p[j]- 90) + k[l % strlen(k)]) % 26 ) + 'a');
        }
        //increment so that next char in k is used
        l++;
    }
    else
    {
        //print unchanged
        printf("%c",p[j]);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you convert the input key `toupper` instead of `tolower`? Caps are historically kind of default (old FORTRAN code was written in all caps) so letters are usually normalized to upper case instead of to lower case. But key should actually have value 0 for letter A, so conversion should actually be `toupper(k[z]) - 'A'` and then afterwards there should be no magic constants involved.

Comment: What is the `get_string` function? What is your input? What is your expected output? What is your actual output?

Comment: To continue my first comment, if you use `- 'A'` part then you can't use `strlen(k)` and must use `k.size()`, because value zero can be part of string and `strlen` considers value zero as string terminator, but `string::size()` does not.

Comment: I changed k[z] = tolower(k[z]); to k[z] = toupper(k[z] - 'A'); and I also changed printf("%c",(((p[j]- 58) + k[l % strlen(k)]) % 26) + 'A'); to printf("%c",(((p[j]- 'A' -6) + k[l % strlen(k)]) % 26) + 'A'); the -6 is because that gives me the right output meaning something is still off I will specify input and output in the description

Comment: Also @RetiredNinja the get_string function prompts the user for a string and I think cs50 "replaced" GetString() with get_string() in the new 2018 course. As I said I now specified all the outputs and the Input in the Description

Comment: Instead od `toupper(k[z] - 'A')` it should be `toupper(k[z]) - 'A'`. But this means that if the key has letter A and you use `strlen` the code will use only part of the key before the letter. You then have to use `string::size` and investigate the error. Or at least introduce new `int k_length = strlen(k)` before contents of `k` is changed, and use `k_length` instead of `strlen(k)` later in code.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works now I still don´t understand why using strlen(k) doesnt work, but assigning it to k_length before making it uppercase does. Could you maybe explain that ? And Thanks again :D

Comment: `strlen` function counts the bytes from given pointer forward until it finds a zero char. With `- 'A'` part we actually turn a previous `A` char into a zero char (which is not the same as `'0'` char; more common name for this zero char is "NUL character"). Calling `strlen` on this changed `k` pointer stops prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

So problem with the code is that the key was not properly normalized. Instead of letter 'A' denoting the value 0 in the key it was denoting the value 97. Using your example we should apply key value for 'b' to letter 'M' to reach encoded letter 'N'. Since 'b' is not 1 but 98 we have to offset that, by subtracting by  97. But since we add 'A' at the end we have to offset that too, by subtracting by 65. Compounded subtraction is 97 + 65 = 162, modulus of which is 162 mod 26 = 6. So you could have subtracted 6 instead of subtracting 58. The result is the same though, since 58 mod 26 is also 6, so you get the same result by using 58 instead of 6.

Next case deals with lower case letter so compounded subtraction is 97 + 97 = 194, and 194 mod 26 = 12. But so is 90 mod 26 = 12, so you get the desired result by using 90 instead of 12.

To avoid the offset needed by the key (97) you can build the key with the correct values (value 0 for letter 'A'). But you have to store the key length before building the key, because function `strlen` will stop counting at value 0 (previous letter 'A'). After that there is still offset for the case (65 and 97), when encoding letters, but their values are at least less confusing.

Comment: Thanks a lot I upvoted but my rank/level isn´t high enough for it to show.Thanks a lot for helping me understand what went wrong where and why :D